# What's the best way to import a python module in a python module without cluttering the modules namepace?

Tags: python, modules, import

Let's say I am writing a python module `module.py`. Which provides functionalities for other parts of my code. Of course, the module has to import other modules. A simple example:

```
import abc as _abc
import typing as _typing

class BaseFunctionality(_abc.ABC):
    def get_sequence(self) -> _typing.Sequence[float]:
        return (1, 2.5, 5.6)
    def get_nested_sequence(self) -> _typing.Sequence[_typing.Sequence[float]]:
        return (1, 2.5, 5.6)
```

As you can see, I am using the "import as underscore" way of importing the modules. I think this is a good way of doing so because:

1. It does not clutter up the module namespace.
2. The modules `abc` and `typing` are visible from outside of `module` as `_abc` and `_typing` where the underscore implies "please don't touch this". They are not part of the module functionality itself.

However, this can be tedious. See for example the definition of `getsequence(self)`. The return type annotation is quite long. And this might get even longer when nesting types. Simply writing `def getsequence(self) -> Sequence[float]:` would be much nicer and more readable, but then I would have to `from typing import Sequence` which adds `Sequence` to the module's namespace. I guess as a compromise I could also `from typing import Sequence as _Sequence` and continue using the annotation with the underscore.

All of this seems rather unpractical. Is there a way to unify the benefits of this way of importing with the benefit of shorter annotations? Of course, in this example I used annotations, but of course, this generalizes to all accesses to the modules.

Comment: What problem are you solving by doing this?

Comment: @KilianFoth If you mean using the `import a as _a`-imports, then it is not a "problem" directly I am trying to solve. The basic idea is that from outside the module you should only access the members that do not start with "_". These would be the internal members from the imported modules. Of course, no one ultimately stops you from accessing them anyway, but this is the cleaner approach.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

```
import abc as _abc
```

Don't do that; it makes your code harder to read.
A simple `import abc` suffices.

I would expect renames such as `_abc` to
be called out during code review,
so the PR wouldn't be merged down to `main` looking like that.

---

Here's what I *didn't* see in your code:

- an `__all__ = [ BaseFunctionality ]` description of what you're trying to export
- a module-level """docstring""" description of what you're trying to export

It also wouldn't hurt to include a """docstring""" on each exported symbol,
such as the `BaseFunctionality` class.